# Adding amplifying information to Bifurcation Diagram

Tags: plotting, graphics

Can more amplifying details be added to this bifurcation diagram to better describe it?

For example, can points (dots and their values) be added where it goes from green to red? Can stability information (stable / unstable points) be added to the contour plot? Any others?

```
  \[Lambda] = D[x^3 - x + a, x];
  Show[ContourPlot[{ConditionalExpression[x^3 - x + a, \[Lambda] < 0] ==
  0, ConditionalExpression[x^3 - x + a, \[Lambda] > 0] == 
  0}, {a, -2, 2}, {x, -2, 2}, Frame -> False, Axes -> True, 
  AxesLabel -> {a, x}, ContourStyle -> {{Green}, {Red, Dashed}}]]
```

Comment: "Can stability information (stable / unstable points) be added to the contour plot?" -- isn't that what green vs red indicates?

Comment: @ChrisK: For someone who knows how to read it, yes. For the uninitiated, it can have a legend that states the ranges of stability of versus instability - at least that is what I was thinking. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"];

f = x^3 - x + a;

λ = D[f, x];

pts = SolveValues[{f == 0, λ == 0}, {a, x}];
```

To add points to a [`ContourPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html) put [`Graphics`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html) in the [`Show`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html)

```
Show[
 ContourPlot[{ConditionalExpression[f, λ < 0] == 0, 
   ConditionalExpression[f, λ > 0] == 0}, {a, -2, 2}, {x, -2, 2},
  Frame -> False,
  Axes -> True,
  AxesLabel ->
   (Style[#, 14] & /@ {a, x}),
  ContourStyle -> {{Green}, {Red, Dashed}}],
 Graphics[{
   AbsolutePointSize[4],
   Point[pts],
   Text[TraditionalForm[pts[[1]]],
    pts[[1]], {1.3, 0}],
   Text[TraditionalForm[pts[[2]]],
    pts[[2]], {-1.3, 0}]}],
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]